# Solve the equation with respect to $k_1,k_2\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, mobius-function

I am struggling with solving the following equation for positive integers $k_1$ and $k_2$ in terms of $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and $i,j\in \mathbb{Z}_+$:

$$n-1=\sum_{i\le k_1,j\le k_2}\sum_{\text{gcd}(i,j)=1}1.$$

Note that this equation can be interpreted also as

$n-1=\sum_{i\le k_1}\sum_{j\le k_2}\sum_{d\ge 1,d|\text{gcd}(i,j)}\mu(d)$

where $\mu$ is the Mobius function defined as

$\mu(n)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n$ is a square-free positive integer with an even number of prime factors}\\
-1 & \text{if $n$ is a square-free positive integers with an odd number of prime factors}\\
0 & \text{if $n$ has a squared prime factor.}
\end{cases}$

Comment: You can rewrite it as $n-1 = \sum_{d \le \max(k_1,k_2)} \mu(d)\lfloor\frac{k_1}{d}\rfloor\lfloor\frac{k_2}{d}\rfloor$, but I doubt you can get an explicit solution for $k_1,k_2$ in terms of $n$.